# facebook link to specific thread of a facebook page inbox

Tags: php, facebook, fbsdk

Basically the title. I can only achieve to open the facebook page inbox but doing this link

```
https://www.facebook.com/{pageid}/messages
```

can somebody help?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: @sobhanbagheri I want to go to a specific chat thread of a facebook page the I am an admin of. how do i assemble the link?

Comment: You could use browser's plugin like HTTP Live header, to see how the request is sent to facebook to open a specific chat thread (either post or get), then try to send the request with that parameter included. I guess you should find a way to have chat thread ids as well.

Comment: @sobhanbagheri got any ideas how to get the thread ids? I'm new to this thing dont know where to look at really

Comment: Im not sure how facebook handles these thread ids. You could get some info by googling or as I said, checking the requests using plugins like HTTP Live Header

Comment: @sobhanbagheri thanks mate!

Comment: You may also take a look at facebook's API. They might have prepared some methods to make it easier for you: developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/messa‌​ge